# How to restructure Power Query script to support sceduled refresh of multiple csv files?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-datasource

I've written PowerQuery script that iterates all files inside a folder. 
For extracting individual file's data I've created PowerQuery function.

Everything works fine in Power BI Desktop, but when I publish the report into Power BI Service and try to schedule refresh - I get error:

(Ty, Olly) Gateway is deployed and all data sources for this report are created and green.

> "Query contains unknown or unsupported data sources. Folder, "E:\myFolder" "

```
let

    fn_ExtractCSVFile = (fileName as text, filePath as text) =>
    let
        Источник = Csv.Document(File.Contents(filePath & "\" & fileName),[Delimiter=",", Columns=15, Encoding=1200, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
        #"Повышенные заголовки" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Источник, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
        #"Удаленные верхние строки" = Table.Skip(#"Повышенные заголовки",1),
        #"Строки с примененным фильтром" = Table.SelectRows(#"Удаленные верхние строки", each ([Год] <> "")),
        #"Замененное значение" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Строки с примененным фильтром",".",",",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Итого"})
    in
        #"Замененное значение",
    Источник = Folder.Files("E:\myFolder"),
    #"Другие удаленные столбцы" = Table.SelectColumns(Источник,{"Name", "Folder Path"}),
    #"Вызвана настраиваемая функция" = Table.AddColumn(#"Другие удаленные столбцы", "Data", each fn_ExtractCSVFile([Name], [Folder Path])),
    #"Развернутый элемент Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Вызвана настраиваемая функция", "Data", {".Организация", "Консолидирующая организация", "Год", "Период отчета", "Проект", "Направление", "Показатель строка0", "Показатель строка", "Родитель первого уровня", "Родитель второго уровня", "Родитель третьего уровня", "Аналитика 1", "Аналитика 3", "Сценарий", "Итого"}, {".Организация", "Консолидирующая организация", "Год", "Период отчета", "Проект", "Направление", "Показатель строка0", "Показатель строка", "Родитель первого уровня", "Родитель второго уровня", "Родитель третьего уровня", "Аналитика 1", "Аналитика 3", "Сценарий", "Итого"})
in
    #"Развернутый элемент Data"
```

Comment: consider installing on-premise data gateway or move your data to the cloud. Nested `lets` nice script :).

Comment: Olly, I have already deployed the gateway (sorry, I've forgotten to mention it in main post). It works, data sources created and green.